# Cannot call script directly by its name after i added location to command search path

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script called testing:

```
$cat testing
echo $1
```

And I also added the location to the PATH in ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="$PATH:some_location/testing"
```

I also did:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

However，when I still could not call the script testing directly by name:

```
$testing 1
-bash: testing: command not found
```

I can still do the following though:

```
$./testing 1
1
```

I’m not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PATH` must be a list of directories, and cannot contain specific filenames.  Edit your .bash_profile line to be:

```
export PATH="$PATH:some_location"
```

Then log out and log back in (or edit your `PATH` manually), and try your script again:

```
$testing 1
1
```

Comment: No need to log out. You can reload bash_profile with: `. ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @Peschke ... and then `PATH` will be `$PATH:some_location/testing:some_location`. The OP needs to set `PATH` back to its initial state before appending `:some_location`. Logging out and logging back in is probably the most expeditious way to accomplish that.

Comment: No need to do anything after fixing PATH for each shell you have open.

Comment: @JimL. That PATH would still work and would be cleaned up either way on next login. Still no need to logout/in to have the change take effect.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Good point, but that's assuming he's using virtual terminals in a GUI environment. If he's ssh'd into a system, it's probably easier to just reload bash_profile instead of opening a new ssh session.